# Replace "selenium-webdriver" with implementation & language binding specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [WebDriver API](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/webdriver/info) was orginally invented by the Selenium project, but in the meanwhile there are many other projects contributing components for the WebDriver API, e.g. [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) as browser-side implementation for PhantomJS, or [WebdriverJS](http://webdriver.io/) as client library for Node.js.

### Removing the selenium-webdriver tag

So in the light of this evolution in the WebDriver ecosystem, what does it mean when it is tagged with [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver)?

1. The question is certainly related to the WebDriver API - but there is a more specific tag for this, which is [webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdriver).
2. It could mean that the question is explicitly about one of the components provided by the selenium project. E.g. one could try to express that one wants to use [Selenium's language binding for JavaScript](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs), and not the one from [webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io/). However, for the information "from the Selenium project", it would already be sufficient to add the [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium) tag. Also, it is unlikely that the tag will be used in this way consistently: e.g. there are 91 questions tagged [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver)[php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), although the [PHP language binding is not provided by the selenium project](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#php).

So the [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) tag really doesn't add enough information to justify its existence, and could just be replaced with [webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdriver).

### Allowing new language binding tags

Instead, there should be tags for the different components offered by the Selenium project. This is for example already the case for [selenium-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-ide) and [selenium-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-grid), but not for the language bindings offered by Selenium. Most WebDriver questions are specific to exactly one language binding, i.e. library that one programs against, so adding such a tag adds very specific information. (You can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3422262/1523648) what happens if this information is missing - you get questions which really should be closed as too broad.)

Language binding sepecific tags existed, e.g. [selenium-webdriver-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver-java) and [selenium-webdriver-c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver-c%23), but these were mapped to [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) as colateral change to the [last WebDriver-related tag cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215586/wrong-tag-synonym-webdriver-selenium). The argument was that e.g. [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver)[java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) would be just as good, but if we want to drop [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver), the alternative [webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdriver)[java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) is really a bit vague description for one specific library for these technologies. Also, when it comes to other programming languages like JavaScript, the argument that "there is only one client library for the WebDriver API" breaks down (see above). So we need tags for the language bindings.

### To summarize (tl;dr:)

- Make [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) an alias of [webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdriver)
- Disassociate [selenium-webdriver-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver-java) and [selenium-webdriver-c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver-c%23) from [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I vehemently oppose the idea of having [selenium-webdriver-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver-java) and similar language-specific tags for Selenium. The fact is that because the bindings provided by the Selenium project (I'm excluding 3rd party libraries) are consistent from language to language, it is usually very easy to understand Selenium posts that use a language the reader is not used to work with.

I've answered Selenium questions in which the OP tagged with a language I've never used (e.g. Ruby, C#) or that I'm not using regularly (e.g. Java). I've also benefited from Selenium answers that were not expressed in languages I use.

Comment: Point taken. Still, the problem remains that "selenium-webdriver" is unspecific/ambiguous. Could we not have a tag just for the Selenium language bindings? E.g. `selenium-webdriver-bindings`?

Comment: Answering my own question: `selenium-webdriver-bindings` is too long. So, we could use... `selenium-webdriver`! So, the only change would be to treat `selenium-webdriver` as tag for the language bindings, and not use it for other Selenium components like the Selenium-Server or the browser implementations.

Comment: Thank you for posting this... I regularly post answers in [selenium], etc. in Java for python Qs and keep getting downvoted for it. It drives me crazy... if you can read that I'm searching for an ID in Java... surely you can translate that into python or whatever. I can google python basics and translate them in 10 minutes but I'd rather be answering the next question...